# Using feature maps with ECP EMF Forms

Tags: eclipse-plugin, emf

I am attempting to use a Feature Map in EMF in order to allow for the editing of arbitrary types in an editor.

I have managed to achieve this so that it is working in the default EMF instance editor but I wish to use ECP in order to build a useful GUI for my plugin. When I attempt to use a control to display this I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.spi.renderer.NoPropertyDescriptorFoundExeption: No Property descriptor was found for the feature "properties" of "Resource". Make sure, the corresponing edit bundle is started.
at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.spi.core.swt.AbstractControlSWTRenderer.createLabel(AbstractControlSWTRenderer.java:232)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.spi.core.swt.SimpleControlSWTRenderer.renderControl(SimpleControlSWTRenderer.java:91)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.spi.swt.AbstractSWTRenderer.render(AbstractSWTRenderer.java:213)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.spi.core.swt.ContainerSWTRenderer.renderControl(ContainerSWTRenderer.java:155)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.spi.swt.AbstractSWTRenderer.render(AbstractSWTRenderer.java:213)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.internal.swt.ECPSWTViewRendererImpl.render(ECPSWTViewRendererImpl.java:82)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.treemasterdetail.ui.swt.internal.TreeMasterDetailSWTRenderer$TreeMasterViewSelectionListener.selectionChanged(TreeMasterDetailSWTRenderer.java:736)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:163)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2171)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1202)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1231)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:408)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:4985)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5367)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDownSuper(Widget.java:1101)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDownSuper(Tree.java:2044)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDown(Widget.java:1093)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseDown(Control.java:2563)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDown(Tree.java:2012)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5627)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Widget.java:2105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Shell.java:2329)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5691)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Display.java:5128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5277)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(NSApplication.java:128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3655)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the property '**Property Type**' value is Editable under the Edit category in .genmodel.